# Unable to connect with wired connection in 12.04

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, command-line, internet-connection

I am having a problem connecting to wired connection from router. I used to have 11.10 where I tried to establish DSL connection. I tried it doing through the terminal using some `pppoeconf` commands.

When I reboot my system, under the Ubuntu loading sign, I saw messages like 
`configuring network`; `wait 60 seconds more for connection`, etc.

Then after 2-3 minutes, Ubuntu home screen appears. When I tried to connect with my wired connection, it always says disconnected even if there is a wired connection.

Then I went to **network** and  tried to connect from there, but I was unable to do so. The wired connection button turns off.

This problem didn't get solved and I also couldn't find a way to undo the settings done from the terminal, so I formatted 11.10 and installed 12.04 but still, the same problem arose.

Comment: If you have User ID  and password for your service provider , do enter that details in Network manager and try again.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!